# Azure Service Bus session state reliability

Tags: azure, architecture, azureservicebus

I am thinking of utilizing azure service bus sessions backed by azure functions to act as orchestrator for running workflows/sagas where each step of the workflow is azure service bus topic/azure function.

I believe service bus trigger functions when they are session enabled, service bus takes care of picking/locking the azure function consumer (can be any one out of 100 instances running in an app service plan). No two consumers can receive messages from the same session. Are there any scenarios where this could fail and corrupt session state?

In terms of resiliency, on a premium tier with zone redundancy enabled and topics partitioning enabled, are there any scenarios in which session state stored on the azure service bus can be lost if the server/VM running the service bus goes down? If yes, what needs to be done in addition to ensure reliability. Also, what is the prescription for this securing this transaction session state along with messages in topics/subscriptions in case of regional outages for DR?

I am trying to follow the example given by @Sean Feldman in https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/sagas-with-azure-service-bus.

Answer (score 0):

> No two consumers can receive messages from the same session. Are there any scenarios where this could fail and corrupt the session state?

No two concurrent receivers (functions) will consume messages from the same session. If there are no messages in the session, after a session timeout (which can be configured), a function instance will move on to the next available session.

> In terms of resiliency, on a premium tier with zone redundancy enabled and topics partitioning enabled, are there any scenarios in which session state stored on the azure service bus can be lost if the server/VM running the service bus goes down?

Azure Service Bus is not running on a single server/VM. It's slightly more complicated than that. Having availability zones and partitioning helps with outages. In case of a real disaster (think Godzilla is visiting the data center), as of today, there's no data plane recovery, only metadata plane. Your entities will fail over to the secondary namespace but not the message. As a reminder, though, this must be a real catastrophic event to take out the data center.

> Also, what is the prescription for securing this transaction session state along with messages in topics/subscriptions in case of regional outages for DR?

The session state is just like another message in the Service Bus store and is subject to the same rules and constraints.

Comment: Thanks Sean for your response. We have to create DR runbooks hence my query regarding same.